# Java setter does not update value

Tags: java, getter-setter

I am trying to make a menu system where the value of some attributes will be updated in another class.

First method

```
 public static void startmenu(){ 
        int path;
        Scanner startscan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println("Enter Shop : 1"); 
        System.out.println("Enter house : 2"); 
        System.out.println("Enter town square : 3"); 
        System.out.println("Leave town : 4"); 
        System.out.println("Check stats : 5"); 
        System.out.println("Chosen path: "); 
        System.out.println("update defence : "); 
        path = startscan.nextInt(); 
        SouthValley(path); 
    }
```

Second method in same class as above where case 6 should update defence to 50 and restart the menu but when I chooose case 5 after it prints 25

```
public static void SouthValley(int selectedPath){
    MainChar Stats = new MainChar();
    do {
        switch(selectedPath){
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("You Entered shop");
                System.out.println("-----------------------------");
                break;
            case 2: 
                System.out.println("You Entered you house");
                break;
            case 3: 
                System.out.println("You Entered Town Square");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("You left the town");
                FirstPath();
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("--------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Defence: " + Stats.getDefence());
                System.out.println("Strength: " + Stats.getStrength());
                System.out.println("Mana: " + Stats.getMana());
                System.out.println("Health: " + Stats.gethealth());
                startmenu();
                break;
            case 6:
                Stats.setDefence(50);
                System.out.println(Stats.getDefence());
                startmenu();
                break;
            default:
                startmenu();
                break;
        }
    }
    while(selectedPath < 7);
}
```

Class with the defined variables

```
public class MainChar {
    private int health = 100;
    private int defence = 25;
    private int strength = 15;
    private int mana = 10;

    public int gethealth(){
        return health;
    }

    public int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }

    public int getDefence() {
        return defence;
    }

    public int getMana() {
        return mana;
    }

    public void setDefence(int Newdefence) {
        this.defence = Newdefence;
    }

    public void setHealth(int Newhealth) {
        this.health = Newhealth;
    }

    public void setMana(int Newmana) {
        this.mana = Newmana;
    }

    public void setStrength(int Newstrength) {
        this.strength = Newstrength;
    }
}
```

I have tried googling a lot but have not fins a solution. This code is just trying to get the value updating to work.

Comment: For me, the question is unclear. You speak of `case 6`, but then of `case 5`. Please [edit] the post, provide a [MRE] (with input, expected and observe output) and clarify the question.

Comment: a new MainChar Stats = new MainChar(); is created each time you call the southValley method

Comment: Some remarks: In Java, variable names should be writtein in `lowerCamelCase` (MainChar Stats = ...` -> `MainChar stats = ...`) --- I would advice to use more descriptive variable names: `MainChar Stats` seems unintutiive. It's either some stats  or a character, using those names interchangably is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The loop creates a new Mainchar every time. Every one of those objects have their own int stored as defence. If you create new one instead of using the one you previously created, it will create a new Mainchar with your default value, 25. that‘s why you get 25 instead of 50.